# Does Yoneda embedding reflect equivalent categories?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Let $\mathsf{Cat}$ denote the category of small categories. For categories $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ in $\mathsf{Cat}$, let $[\mathcal A,\mathcal B]$ denote the category whose objects are functors form $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$ and morphisms are natural transformation between those functors. My question is

> Given a functor $F:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$. Suppose for any $\mathcal C\in\text{ob}\mathsf{Cat}$ we have $F^*:[\mathcal B,\mathcal C]\to[\mathcal A,\mathcal C]$ is an equivalence, or for any $\mathcal C\in\text{ob}\mathsf{Cat}$ we have $F_*:[\mathcal C,\mathcal A]\to[\mathcal C,\mathcal B]$ is an equivalence. Can we deduce that $F$ is an equivalence?

Comment: Partial answer: if $F_* : [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{A}] \to [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{B}]$ is an equivalence for all categories $\mathcal{C}$, then in particular $F_* : [\mathbb{1},\mathcal{A}] \to [\mathbb{1},\mathcal{B}]$ is an equivalence, where $\mathbb{1}$ is the terminal category. But $\mathcal{A} \cong [\mathbb{1},\mathcal{A}]$ and $\mathcal{B} \cong [\mathbb{1},\mathcal{B}]$, and these isomorphisms commute with $F$ and $F_*$, so that $F$ is also an equivalence.

Comment: I'm removing the "higher category theory" tag; and I question the use of the phrase "Yoneda Embedding"  in the title, as this has nothing to do with Yoneda.

Comment: ("Monoidal categories" is also off topic, but less egregiously.)

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: It has very much to do with Yoneda!

Comment: @HeinrichD - 2-Yoneda, perhaps, but I'd argue that various extended forms (2-Yoneda, enriched Yoneda) are not what "Yoneda embedding" and "Yoneda lemma", without modifiers, are usually understood to cover. The question itself is entirely asked, and answerable, without any serious 2-categorical result.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine It has something to do with Yoneda. And I think that's enough to justify my using this word in the title. period

Comment: It has "something" to do with a number of things, few of which merit mention. But as you like it.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Since when just mentioning a name become such a serious  matter that even arouses a question about  whether it merits mention? If you find that the mere mention of Yoneda have the effect on disturbing your thinking,  that's just you.

Comment: All I commented was that it seemed irrelevant, followed by a brief case for why it was irrelevant; I'm not sure why this would count as making a big deal. I honestly wouldn't even be commenting at this point if I wasn't still getting @'s at my name.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine If I don't get wrong, you made two points. The first is it seems irrelevant; the second is - after others explaining why it's relevant - it doesn't merit mention. Please don't mix up your first point with my reply regarding your second point.

Comment: Oh, I never conceded that it was relevant; my second point is still just my first.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine "It has 'something' to do with a number of things, few of which merit mention" That sounds very much like a concession to me. But if you insist on that, I think we can at least come to agreement that it's not a big deal.

Comment: Tangential relation is not the same as relevance, in my book. In any case, you're right, I did not think any of this merited an entire thread....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is a special case of the $2$-categorical Yoneda Lemma. Here is a direct proof.

Assume that $F^*$ is an equivalence for all categories $C$. In particular, $F^* : [B,A] \to [A,A]$ is essentially surjective. Choose some $G : B \to A$ with $GF \cong \mathrm{id}_A$. We have $FG \cong \mathrm{id}_B$ since $FGF \cong \mathrm{id}_B F$ and $F^* : [B,B] \to [A,B]$ is fully faithful.

You can use the same proof for $F_*$. Or you can give a quick argument as shown by Clive Newstead in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any reference about 2-categorical Yoneda Lemma?

Comment: See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma+for+bicategories and Section 3.6.2 in Vistoli's *Notes on Grothendieck topologies, ...* (but the proof is very sketchy).